# How to write a regular expression for javascript valiadation

Tags: javascript, regex

```
^[A-Z0-9]*[ _][A-Z0-9]*$

space cannot be accepted either at the beginning or end.
space cannot be accepted  at all instead of the value.
allow numbers and characters in the start and end.
allow hyphens in the middle not mandatory
```

All these values are accepted values

```
12345
ABC-12345
MM 1.8.10
530715 HS 9JAXXX4100
020-59898
HLXU1234
```

But when i type ABC BCD. It says it is not correct match

Comment: when i type ABC BCD. It says it is not correct match

Comment: *"allow hyphens in the middle not mandatory"* What exactly can be or not be in the middle? And do you require at least one character for the start and end parts?

Comment: *"when i type ABC BCD. It says it is not correct match"* Your regex matches for me.

Comment: hyphens or space can be in the middle.Character or number any thing can be starting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[^ ]([\w- \.]+)[^ ]$
```

`[^ ]` = cannot start or end with space

`([\w- .]+)` = all characters allowed (or in this case, \w, hyphen, space and dot)

matches:
ABC BCD

Comment: You can, of course, replace ([\w- \.]+) with ([A-Z0-9 -\.]+) depending on your precision required.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's clearer to separate the regex into multiple ones.

```
function validate (str) {
    if (/^\s|\s$/.test(str)) { // starts or ends with a space
        return false;
    }
    if (/^-|-$/.test(str)) { // starts or ends with a hyphen
        return false;
    }
    return /[\s\w-]+/.test(str); // ensure all valid characters and non-empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a 100% sure what you mean because in the allowed example values you have

> MM 1.8.10

which does not follow the rule set you specified.

that is why I based the pattern on your example values, this should work

**`^[A-Z0-9]+(?:[ _.-][A-Z0-9]+){0,3}$`**

Explanation

`^` start match at the beginning of the string

`[A-Z0-9]+` match one or more uppercase alphanumeric characters, thus empty values will fail

`(?:` start a non-capturing group, this group will allow a separator followed by again at least one alphanumeric uppercase character, which is mandatory, so the value must begin and end with alphanumeric characters and the separators are only allowed in between.

`[ _.-]` match one space, underscore, dot or hyphen

`[A-Z0-9]+` match one or more uppercase alphanumeric characters

`)` close the non-capturing group

`{0,3}` this allows the group to be matched 0 or up to 3 times.

`$` match the end of the string

In the last part `{0,3}$` the 3 is there to allow only up to 3 extra (so 4 in total) uppercase alphanumeric character groupings separated by a space, underscore, dot or hyphen, you can change the 3 into any digit you want or remove it to allow 0 or unlimited groupings.

Example script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var strings = [
    'ABC BCD',
    '12345',
    'ABC-12345',
    'MM 1.8.10',
    '530715 HS 9JAXXX4100',
    '020-59898',
    'HLXU1234'
]
var matches = '';
for(i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    matches += i + ' : ' + strings[i].match(/^[A-Z0-9]+(?:[ _.-][A-Z0-9]+){0,3}$/) + '\n';
}
window.alert(matches);
</script>
```