# How to make the below regex to accept any special character

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/^[^ ]([\w- \.\\\/&#]+)[^ ]$/,
```

I have the above regex. I want to make sure it accepts all special characters  but i don't want to specify the entire special character  listsuch as  `[\w- \.\\\/&#!@#$&]`. How can we make sure the above regex accepts all special characters

Comment: How do you define special characters?

Comment: We would probably give the most useful regexes if we had a sample line to match.  As is, I believe /^[^ ](.+)[^ ]$/ is the best match thus far, since all we have to work with is the 'spirit' of your example: allow all characters, matches the start and end of the line but does not have leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[^\w\s]` matches any non-alphanumeric and non-whitespace character.

`\S` matches any non-whitespace character.

`.` matches any character except newlines.

`[\S\s]` matches *any* character in a JavaScript regex.

Comment: Don't forget that underscore is part of `\w` (not just "alphanumeric")

Comment: Tim, remember that’s only going to work on legacy 7-bit data unless you pull in the [XRegExp plugin for Javascript](http://xregexp.com/plugins/). I know you know this, but a lot of people don’t.  Now that the web is over 80% Unicode, our patterns need to be able to cope with it. I have heard nothing that the excema people are trying to modernize to this century; if you do, please let me know. Meanwhile, Javascript will call something like `ñ` a nonword character and stuff like no-break space (code point U+00A0) a non-whitespace character.  Both are wrong.  XRegExp will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got `\w` and a space in there already, you must want all of the ASCII characters except control characters.  That would be:

```
[ -~]
```

...or any character whose code point is in the range `U+0020` (space) to `U+007E` (tilde).  But it looks like you want to make sure the first and last characters are not whitespace.  In fact, looking at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9284524/20938), I'll assume you want only letters or digits in those positions.  This would work:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9][ -~]*[A-Za-z0-9]$/
```

...but that requires the string to be at least two characters long.  To allow for a single-character string, change it to this:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[ -~]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$/
```

In other words, if there's only one character, it must be a letter or digit.  If there are two or more characters, the first and last must letters or digits, while the rest can be any *printing* character--i.e., a letter, a digit, a "special" (punctuation) character, or a space.

Note that this only matches ASCII characters, not accented Latin letters like `Â` or `ë`, or symbols from other alphabets or writing systems.

Comment: Alan, see my comment to Tim about [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/plugins/). It’s imperfect but infinitely preferable to regular Javascript.  I have never seen a glimmer that the eczema people care one whingeing whit about minimal conformance with [Level 1 of UTS#18 on Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Basic_Unicode_Support). Java 7, Perl, and Matthew Barnett’s `regex` module for Python all finally manage that, but there is no “scripting” language for client-side webrowsers that meets the spec.  It’s a real bother. Very antedeluvian.

Comment: Even simple currency needs more than `$5.95`, since you can have `£10-pound notes` or `39¢ candies`.  Even old typewriters had ¢ signs, alas. And of course now you have € all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

`.` matches any character except for newline.

Comment: Actually, [.]  matches only dot, and nothing else. A dot without the brackets though, would do as you say.